# Overystayed visa as a minor, can I now get an F1 to study?

Tags: visas, overstaying, minors, f1-visas

I was taken to the US when I was 11, in 1999 with a parent. We stayed illegally until u decided to move back to my home country voluntarily in 2005 when I was 17, I was becoming an adult and realizing my illegal status and all the problems I had started to face due to that. After ten years of living in my home country, I decided I wanted to visit the US and in 2015 I applied for a tourist visa. I had a good job for about 7 years at that point and was honest about my overstayed time on my application. I was able to receive my visa without issue and is valid for ten years. Since 2015, I have made annual trips to vacation in the US and have never overstayed my time. I now want to apply for an F1 visa because I want to attend school in the US. Will I have any issue getting this? I’m assuming they won’t be very hard on me since I currently have a tourist visa which I have not abused, plus I was a minor at the time I overstayed and it wasn’t my choice to do so, I also left voluntarily before I turned 18.

Comment: Overstay as a minor isn't held against you, as far as I'm aware: as you say, it wasn't your choice. But questions about long-term visits, such as study and employment, are off-topic here and need to be asked at [expatriates.se], instead.

Answer (score 5):

One can never predict for certain what will happen with an application, but if you got a ten year tourist visa it seems they are not holding your overstay against you (indeed they shouldn't since you were a minor and thus didn't accrue illegal presence), so from your question I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be eligible for an F1 if you were enrolling at a legitimate institution.